# com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException

Tags: java, ios

Each second time I open my iOS app using Cassandra, I got the exception: `com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException`.

The following actions I made:

- Change the driver to 2.1.3: https://github.com/datastax/java-driver

I guess the driver should be updated to 2.1.4, but I can't add from:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
  <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

to:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
  <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: the following actions to fix this is https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/wiki/Connection-requirements and not updating to 1.4 as it isn´t released yet